# iOS: Values for CIFilter (Hue) from Photoshop

Tags: iphone, ios, image-processing, photoshop, hue

I am using the `Hue` filter to change the hue of an image:

```
CIFilter* hueFilter = 
     [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIHueAdjust" <blah blah> 
        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:hue], nil];
```

I have the `Hue` number I wish to use from `Photoshop`, but it doesn't correspond to the results I get from iOS.

Is there a rule to change the number in `PhotoShop` to the number I should use in `iOS`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Hue in HSL/HSV color mode is an angular coordinate.
In Photoshop, it is given in degrees (-180 to +180).

In the CIHueAdjust filter, the angle is given in radians.
From http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIHueAdjust

> **Parameters**
>
> *inputAngle*
>
> An `NSNumber` class whose attribute type is `CIAttributeTypeAngle` and whose display name is Angle.
>
> Default value: 0.00 Minimum: 0.00 Maximum: 0.00 Slider minimum: -3.14 Slider maximum: 3.14 Identity: 0.00

The formula to go from Photoshop value (degrees) to CIHueAdjust value (radians) is a linear conversion:

```
filterAngle = photoshopAngle * π / 180
```

Comment: It's also fair to add that the given `inputAngle` is not the final hue angle value but rather the angle for which the color cube will be rotated for. That said, if initial hue is `20` and you input an angle of value `10` the resulting hue value will be `30` and not `10`.

Comment: Hey @lodeRunner have you done this but with the Saturation? Thanks!