# Get hue value from a UIColor?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, nsnumber

I am using the following code to change hue of UIImage

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];

// Create a Core Image version of the image.
CIImage *sourceCore = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage]];

// Apply a CIHueAdjust filter
CIFilter *hueAdjust = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIHueAdjust"];
[hueAdjust setDefaults];
[hueAdjust setValue: sourceCore forKey: @"inputImage"];
[hueAdjust setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 1.0f] forKey: @"inputAngle"];
CIImage *resultCore = [hueAdjust valueForKey: @"outputImage"];

// Convert the filter output back into a UIImage.
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef resultRef = [context createCGImage:resultCore fromRect:[resultCore extent]];

UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:resultRef];
CGImageRelease(resultRef);
```

The code works fine, i'm just trying to find a way to get the correct NSNumber values of inputAngle for the specific colors.

so can i maybe:

1. Get the value by  converting a `[UIColor colorWithRed:0.89 green:0.718 blue:0.102 alpha:1.0]`
2. or maybe just use the UIColor in some way ?
3. or is there any list with the specific numbers for each color ?

The docs says:

[image: CIHueAdjust]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post might answer your question:

[Is there function to convert UIColor to Hue Saturation Brightness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071756/is-there-function-to-convert-uicolor-to-hue-saturation-brightness)

The angle should be the hue value you get there.

Here you find some information on how the angle has to be understood:

[iOS: Values for CIFilter (Hue) from Photoshop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765244/ios-values-for-cifilter-hue-from-photoshop)

**EDIT**

Here is some example code based on yours:

First let's define the color you want to filter (for your inputAngle)

```
UIColor *myColor = [UIColor redColor]; // The color you want to filter
```

Then we determine the hue value of that color (that's the actual inputAngle)

```
CGFloat hue;
CGFloat saturation;
CGFloat brightness;
CGFloat alpha;
[myColor getHue:&hue saturation:&saturation brightness:&brightness alpha:&alpha];
```

This is your code (unchanged)

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png"];

// Create a Core Image version of the image.
CIImage *sourceCore = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage]];

// Apply a CIHueAdjust filter
CIFilter *hueAdjust = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIHueAdjust"];
[hueAdjust setDefaults];
[hueAdjust setValue: sourceCore forKey: @"inputImage"];
```

Here we apply the filter using the determined hue value of the chosen color

```
[hueAdjust setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: hue] forKey: @"inputAngle"];
```

This is your code (unchanged)

```
CIImage *resultCore = [hueAdjust valueForKey: @"outputImage"];

// Convert the filter output back into a UIImage.
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CGImageRef resultRef = [context createCGImage:resultCore fromRect:[resultCore extent]];

UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:resultRef];
CGImageRelease(resultRef);
```

Hope this fits your needs.

Comment: I actually went through these questions while searching, but i didn't get to solve my issue

Comment: I have changed my whole code and used `CIColorMonochrome` of `CIFiler` instead `CIHueAdjust` to change images color, but your answer is great, and pretty sure will help others, thank you!